# Sets, Discrete Structures

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I just started my discrete structures class, and i'm reading about sets..

Only thing that's puzzling me, and the book doesn't explain really.

A ∪ B = {x : x ∈ A or x ∈ B}

from what i've gathered, x is in A or x is in B, because of the union. But what exactly does the notation "x : x" mean??

Answer (score 3):

The "$:$" means "such that." So, an expression like "$\{x: x$ is blue$\}$" would be read "The set of $x$ such that $x$ is blue," or - in better English - "The set of blue things." Sometimes a vertical line is used instead of a colon - e.g. "$\{x\vert x>7\}$."

As an aside, "$\in$" doesn't mean "is between," it means "is in" (or more precisely, "is an element of").

Comment: Thank you! I don't know if I was suppose to know that, but the book used by my class didn't explain that at all. Also, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @beatles1235 This is sometimes called "set builder notation" if you want to google around to find other sources talking about it.

Comment: Will do, thanks!